# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pooling_mode_weightedmean_tokens'

Tags: huggingface, weaviate

I am attempting to index and vectorize a test document into Weaviate using Huggingface's `instructor-xl`, but I am getting this error. Does anyone know how to resolve? Code below.

Schema creation script:

```
load_dotenv()

client = weaviate.Client(
    url="http://localhost:8080",
    additional_headers={"X-HuggingFace-Api-Key": os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_APIKEY")},
)

client.schema.delete_class("Blah")

class_obj = {
    "class": "Blah",
    "properties": [
        {
            "dataType": ["text"],
            "name": "title",
            "tokenization": "whitespace",
        },
        {
            "dataType": ["text"],
            "name": "summary",
            "tokenization": "whitespace",
        },
        {
            "dataType": ["text"],
            "name": "description",
            "tokenization": "whitespace",
        },
    ],
    "vectorizer": "text2vec-huggingface",
    "moduleConfig": {
        "text2vec-huggingface": { 
            "skip": False,
            "vectorizePropertyName": False,
            "model": "hkunlp/instructor-xl",
            "options": {"waitForModel": True},
        }
    },
    "invertedIndexConfig": {"indexTimestamps": True, "indexNullState": True},
}

client.schema.create_class(class_obj)
```

Indexing script:

```
client = weaviate.Client(
        url="http://localhost:8080",
        additional_headers={"X-HuggingFace-Api-Key": os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_APIKEY")},
    )
class_name = "Blah"
df = pd.read_json("blah.json")
    with client.batch() as batch:
        for i in [data_obj]:
            batch.add_data_object(i, class_name)
```

Docker-compose file:

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.19.6
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    restart: on-failure:0
    volumes:
      - /var/weaviate:/var/lib/weaviate
    environment:
      SUM_INFERENCE_API: 'http://sum-transformers:8080'
      HUGGINGFACE_APIKEY: $HUGGINGFACE_APIKEY
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-huggingface'
      ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-huggingface,sum-transformers'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
  sum-transformers:
    image: semitechnologies/sum-transformers:facebook-bart-large-cnn-1.0.0
    environment:
      ENABLE_CUDA: '0'
```

Code that I have tried is above

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: what is the error you're getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when vectorizing documents with `Salesforce/SFR-Embedding-Mistral embeddings`. I solved it by upgrading `sentence-transformers` to `2.5.1` and
`transformers` to `4.38.2`.